# Yesod Location Header

Tags: rest, haskell, handler, yesod

I have to set a location header in a post handler response, putting the location where the newly created entity is placed. How can I do it dynamically?

The target route (where it will be placed) has this definition:

```
/exchanges/#ExchangeId ExchangeByIdR GET PUT
```

**EDIT**

I would like a function like this one:

```
addLocationHeader (ExchangeByIdR eId)
```

Comment: Do you just want to use [`addHeader`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.8/yesod-core-1.4.19/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:addHeader)?

Comment: Not exactly, I would like something like this: `setLocationHeader (ExchangeByIdR eId)`...

Comment: Ah ok. I think [`sendResponseCreated`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.8/yesod-core-1.4.19/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:sendResponseCreated) might be appropriate?

Comment: @MaxGabriel Exactly! It is what I was looking for. I think you should make it an answer.

Comment: @MaxGabriel, I realised it is not right, it is not sending the json data as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply created my own function `addLocationHeader`:

```
addLocationHeader :: MonadHandler m => Route (HandlerSite m) -> m ()
addLocationHeader url = do
  r <- getUrlRender
  addHeader "Location" (r url)
```